# Deploying SP 2016 wsp to SP 2019 but resulting in error for Add-SP Solution

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-2019

I have tried to Deploy SP 2016 wsp to SP 2019 but that resul in error for Add-SP Solution Input string was not in correct format at line 1.

I have opened the SP 2016  wsp in VS 2017 in an environment with the SP 2019 installed. 
Also upgraded the solution when asked by VS 2017 to SP 2019.

It rebuild the wsp properly but not deploying.

Can anyone give me some idea on this?

Error which I am getting is:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'SPList' exists in both 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' and 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'  Bamboo.FullTextSearch   C:\Bamboo\LT200\SPX.HW11.ListSearch\dev\Bamboo.AdvanceSearchSolnDual\Bamboo.FullTextSearch\Bamboo.SimpleSearchEngine.cs 48  Active**

There are lot of like this

Answer (score 0):

1) Check references in your project: Microsoft.SharePoint.

2) If there is a reference and it's not corrupted, check the version by opening library properties.

2.1) If you have referenced a newer version, add an assembly binding with bindingRedirect in app config, for example:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SharePoint" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.0.0.0" newVersion="16.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

3) Enable the Fusion log [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) and read the logs.